# How to concatenate (merge) AAStringSets by name?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

In bioinformatics/microbial ecology literature a fairly common practice is to concatenate multiple sequence alignments of multiple genes prior to building phylogenetic trees.  In R terminology it may be clearer to say 'merge' these sequences by the organism they came from, but I'm sure examples are better.

Say these are two multiple sequence alignments.

```
library(Biostrings)

set1<-AAStringSet(c("IVR", "RDG", "LKS"))
names(set1)<-paste("org", 1:3, sep="_")

set2<-AAStringSet(c("VRT", "RKG", "AST"))
names(set2)<-paste("org", 2:4, sep="_")
```

set1

```
A AAStringSet instance of length 3
    width seq    names               
[1]     3 IVR    org_1
[2]     3 RDG    org_2
[3]     3 LKS    org_3
```

set2

```
A AAStringSet instance of length 3
    width seq    names               
[1]     3 VRT    org_2
[2]     3 RKG    org_3
[3]     3 AST    org_4
```

The correct concatenation of these sequences would be

```
A AAStringSet instance of length 4
    width seq    names               
[1]     6 IVR--- org_1
[2]     6 RDGVRT org_2
[3]     6 LKSRKG org_3
[4]     6 ---AST org_4
```

The "-" notes a 'gap' (lack of amino acid) in that position, or in this case a lack of a gene to concatenate.

I thought there would be a function to do this in `BioStrings`, `MSA`, `DECIPHER`, or other related packages, but have been unable to find one.

I found the following Q&As, each does not provide the desired output as described.

1: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/38955/

output

```
  A AAStringSet instance of length 6
    width seq names               
[1]     3 IVR org_1
[2]     3 RDG org_2
[3]     3 LKS org_3
[4]     3 VRT org_2
[5]     3 RKG org_3
[6]     3 AST org_4
```

May be better described as 'appending' the sequences (joins the two sets vertically).

2: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/39878/

output

```
  A AAStringSet instance of length 2

        width seq
    [1]     9 IVRRDGLKS
    [2]     9 VRTRKGAST
```

Concatenates sequences in each set, a complete chimera of each set (certainly not desired).

3: [How to concatenate two DNAStringSet sequences per sample in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308134/how-to-concatenate-two-dnastringset-sequences-per-sample-in-r)

output

```
  A AAStringSet instance of length 3
    width seq
[1]     6 IVRVRT
[2]     6 RDGRKG
[3]     6 LKSAST
```

Creates chimeras of sequences by the order they are in.  Even worse with different number of sequences (loops and concatenates shorter set...)

4: https://www.biostars.org/p/115192/

Output

```
  A AAStringSet instance of length 2
    width seq
[1]     3 IVR
[2]     3 VRT
```

Only appends the first sequence from each set, not sure why anyone wants this...

I would normally think these kinds of processes would be done with some combination of `bash` and `Python`, but I'm using the `DECIPHER` multiple sequence aligner in `R`, so it makes sense to do the rest of the processing in `R`.  In the process of writing up this question I came up with an answer that I will post, but I'm kind of expecting someone to point me to the manual I missed that describes the function that does this.  Thanks!

Comment: Would be nice to add the actual code you used in addition to those links.

Answer (score 1):

So I am a somewhat fanatical user of `data.table` in `R`, among many things it is great to merge datasets by names.  I found `Biostrings::AAStringSet`s can be converted to matrices using `as.matrix` and these can be converted to `data.table` and merged.

```
set1.dt<-data.table(as.matrix(set1), keep.rownames = TRUE)
set2.dt<-data.table(as.matrix(set2), keep.rownames = TRUE)
set12.dt<-merge(set1.dt, set2.dt, by="rn", all=TRUE)
    set12.dt
      rn V1.x V2.x V3.x V1.y V2.y V3.y
1: org_1    I    V    R <NA> <NA> <NA>
2: org_2    R    D    G    V    R    T
3: org_3    L    K    S    R    K    G
4: org_4 <NA> <NA> <NA>    A    S    T
```

This is the correct merge, but needs more work to get the final result.

Need to replace "NA" with "-".  I always need to look up this question to remember the best way to do this with a `data.table`.

#### [Fastest way to replace NAs in a large data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table)

```
#slightly modified from original, added arg "x"
f_dowle = function(dt, x) {     # see EDIT later for more elegant solution
      na.replace = function(v,value=x) { v[is.na(v)] = value; v }
      for (i in names(dt))
        eval(parse(text=paste("dt[,",i,":=na.replace(",i,")]")))
    }
    
f_dowle(set12.dt, "-")
```

Concatenate the sequences (not included the names with `!"rn"`)

```
set12<-apply(set12.dt[ ,!"rn"], 1, paste, collapse="")
```

Convert back to `AAStringSet` and add back names

```
set12<-AAStringSet(set12)
names(set12)<-set12.dt$rn
```

Desired output

```
set12
 A AAStringSet instance of length 4
    width seq names               
[1]     6 IVR--- org_1
[2]     6 RDGVRT org_2
[3]     6 LKSRKG org_3
[4]     6 ---AST org_4
```

This works, but seems quite cumbersome, especially converting between different data formats.  Obviously can wrap it into a function to use more easily, but again seems like this should already be a function in some `Bioconductor` package...

Comment: Why `as.matrix`? If we do `as.data.frame`, then we only have 2 columns instead of 6. And replacing `NA` with `"---"` would be simpler: `set12.dt[ is.na(set12.dt) ] <- "---"` ?